# MongoDB/Mongoose Insert array objects which has an array objects

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have the following mongo schema:

```
const schema = mongoose.Schema({
    months: [{
        performance: [{
            yield: Number,
            angle: Number,
        }]
    }],
    createdAt: {
        type: Date,
        default: new Date(),
    },
});
```

I want to initialise this collection with the following document:

```
{
            "months": [
                {
                    "performance": [
                        {
                            "yield": 256,
                            "angle": 40
                        },
                        {
                            "yield": 256,
                            "angle": 40
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "peformance": [
                        {
                            "yield": 256,
                            "angle": 40
                        }
                    ]
                },
            ]
        },
```

I run Collection.insertMany(elements);

In the db I only see months.performance, and performance is indicated to be an array but is always empty (Yield and Angle never get stored).It looks like mongo doesnt insert nested arrays, or I am doing something wrong.

** Also would there be an alternate way to model this type of Schema that is recommended? **

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks